# Compute $v_2\left(2005^{2^{100}}-2003^{2^{100}}\right)$

Tags: number-theory

Compute $v_2\left(2005^{2^{100}}-2003^{2^{100}}\right)$ where $v_2(n)$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing $n$.

I think one way to solve this is to use the binomial theorem with $2005=2003+2$, but you have to know something about the largest power of two dividing binomial coefficients. I'm not sure if that behaves nicely, and its not strictly increasing with the lower index. I believe the answer is $103$. Please do not kill the problem with Lifiting the Exponent Lemma. If this is the only method, I suppose you can include a solution. I already know the lemma

$v_2(x^n-y^n)=v_2(x-y)+v_2(x+y)+v_2(n)-1$

for $x,y$ odd integers, which solves the problem instantly. But it is somewhat obscure and this requires no ingenuity to apply.

Comment: Have you tried Lifting the Exponent?

Comment: Lifting the Exponent is the right approach.  There is a very short, direct proof using properties of the $p$-adic exponential, and also an elementary one that is a little longer and less intuitive.

Comment: See my edit. I want to avoid using LTE.  Ahaan nice to see you here instead of AoPS which I will never use again.

Comment: $n$ being even is required too for your lemma.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou I am not here _instead_ of AoPS. I am here as well as on AoPS, which I will use regardless of your completely unnecessary comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We note that $2005 \equiv 1 \equiv -2003 \bmod 4$

Hence $2005^{2r}+2003^{2r}\equiv 2 \bmod 4$

We also note that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ so that $$2005^{2^{100}}-2005^{2^{100}}=\left(2005^{2^{99}}+2005^{2^{99}}\right)\cdot \left(2005^{2^{99}}-2005^{2^{99}}\right)=$$$$=\left(2005^{2^{99}}+2005^{2^{99}}\right)\cdot \left(2005^{2^{98}}+2005^{2^{98}}\right)\cdot\left(2005^{2^{98}}-2005^{2^{98}}\right)$$ where you can increase the number of factors with a $+$ each time, and each of these contributes $1$ to the valuation, until you get to the point where the exponent is not even $$\dots (2005+2003)(2005-2003)$$

The dots represent $99$ factors with exponents $2^{99}\dots 2^1$ contributing $99$ to the valuation. $2005+2003=4008$ which is divisible by $8$ not $16$, so is worth $3$, and $2005-2003=2$ is worth $1$. I make that $103$.

This effectively replicates the proof of the lemma using only elementary observations

Comment: Wow. I am an idiot. Why did I not see difference of squares?!?!?! Thank you for the nice solution. You are also correct about the lemma. Actually I had not seen the proof of the lemma before hand. I did not realize it was this simple. Now I can rederive it when needed!

Comment: I did see the difference of squares, but I thought it would go $100\to50\to25$ and stop there since $25$ was odd. I'm still kind of puzzled as to how $(2005^{2^{99}})^2=2005^{2^{100}}$... But thinking about it, I realize that my thought of $100,50,25$ would have been correct had the exponent been $100$ and not $2^{100}$. In other words, your solution works because $2^{99}+2^{99}=2^{100}$. Nice... +1.

Comment: @barakmanos There is an old BMO problem (I think that is the source) to find four prime factors of $3^{16}-2^{16}$ which is easily solved like this (only one of the factors takes any work) - I always think of that when I see these power towers, to make sure I haven't confused myself.

Comment: Yep, but this one is easier, since the tower is only one story high :)

Comment: @barakmanos Look at it as $3^{2^4}-2^{2^4}=(3^{2^3}+2^{2^3})(3^{2^2}+2^{2^2})(3^{2^1}+2^{2^1})(3^{2^0}+2^{2^0})(3^{2^0}-2^{2^0})$