# Modular arithmetic - Calculating a large power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is from a contest. I am trying to solve:

What is the largest power $n$ such that $7^{2048} - 1$ is divisible by $4^n$.

So far I have been trying with $7^{2^{11}} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{2n}}$

Then I have tried some brute-force calculations to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $(7^{1024}+1)(7^{512}+1)\cdots (7^2+1)(7+1)(7-1)$.

Note that if $x$ is odd, then $x^2+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Coincidentally the same method [used in another answer today](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1176923/107671). You can generalize this to $v_2(a^n-b^n)=v(a+b)+v(a-b)+v(n)-1\iff a,b\in\mathbb Z, |a|\neq |b|,$ $a,b$ odd, $n$ even, where $v_p(n)$ is the largest $\alpha\in\mathbb N_0$ such that $p^\alpha\mid n$, $v(0)=\infty$. This is a part of the Lifting the Exponent Lemma (LTE).

Comment: @Andrew: We get exactly one $2$ for $1024,512, \dots, 2$, so $10$ of them. And $3$ more from $7+1$, and another from $7-1$, total $14$, so $4^7$ is la  the largest power of $4$ that divides $7^{2048}-1$. Some idea works for $2^w$ instead of $2048=2^{11}$. Increasing $w$ by $1$ gies us one extra $2$.

Comment: Thanks, started to try to write that and my computer crashed - really. I appreciate you taking me home.

Comment: @user314 Thanks for the link - very nice

Comment: You are welcome. The factorization I mentioned is useful elsewhere, for example in proving that any two Fermat numbers $2^{2^k}+1$ are relatively prime.